# Using batch scripting to re-name multiple .pdf files

Tags: batch-rename

### I am trying to re-name multiple .pdf files using two numerals from the existing .pdf, and re-naming each .pdf with a set prefix.

In my example, I have 30 or so .pdfs named "DR DES LSEC01.pdf", "DR DES LSEC02.pdf" and so on.. up to "DR DES LSEC32.pdf". I want to keep the existing numerals (i.e. 01, 02, 03 etc.), and then add on a pre-fix (in my example, the pre-fix is "DS2019.000450-CD-SM-03").

I have created a looped batch file to loop through each .pdf and rename each by copying (I have also tried to use the rename function to no avail).

Currently, if I run the code, it either says:
1) Syntax is incorrect (if I use the 'ren' function); or
2) The system cannot find the file specified (if I use the copy function)

### Here is the code

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set A="DR DES LSEC"                                                                                                                                                                 
set prefix=DS2019.000450-CD-SM-03

For %%a in (%A%) do (                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        For %%f in ( %%a*.pdf ) do (
            set oldfilename=%%~nf
            set oldname=!oldfilename:~-2!
            set newname=!prefix!-!oldname!
            echo %%f
            echo !newname!
            copy y/ %%f !newname!.pdf
        )
)
pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try out below snippet

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set A="DR DES LSEC"                                                                                                                                                                 
set prefix=DS2019.000450-CD-SM-03

For %%a in (%A%) do (                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        For %%f in ( %%a*.pdf ) do (
            set oldfilename=%%~nf
            set oldname=!oldfilename:~-2!
            set newname=!prefix!-!oldname!
            echo %%~nf
            echo !newname!
            copy y/ %%~nf !newname!.pdf
        )
)
pause
```